# Como añadir un sistema de doble factor

Tags: php, pdo

hola me gustaria crear un sistema de doble factor para proteger los datos de los usuarios 
este es mi login script

```
<?php session_start();
require('admincp/config.php');
require('function.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

}else {
  header('Location:'.RUTA.'home');
}

$message = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = specialtext($_POST['username']);
  $password = specialtext($_POST['password']);
  $password = hash('sha512', $password);

  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=',"","");
  //$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE usuario = :username AND pasword = :password");
  $statement->bindParam(':username', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $statement->bindParam(':password', $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetch();
  if ($result !=false) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['id'];
    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;

    header('Location:'.RUTA.'auth');
  }else {
    $message .= '<span class="error">Usuario o contraseña incorrecto</span>';
  }
}

require('view/login.view.php');
?>
```

y este es mi register.php script

```
<?php session_start();

require('admincp/config.php');
require('function.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = specialtext($_POST['username']);
  $password = specialtext($_POST['password']);
  $password = hash('sha512', $password);
  $tipo = "user";


  $message = '';
  if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    $message .= '<span class="error">Rellene todos los campos</span>';
  }else{
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=',"","");
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE usuario = :username LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetch();

    if ($result != false) {
      $message .= '<span class="error">Ya existe este usuario</span>';
    }
  }

  if ($message == '') {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=',"","");
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO user(usuario, pasword, tipo, avatar) VALUES (:username,:password,:tipo,'default.png')");
    $statement->execute([
      ':username' => $username,
      ':password' => $password,
      ':tipo' => $tipo
    ]);
    header('Location:'.RUTA.'login');
  }

}
require('view/register.view.php');

 ?>
```

Ahora mi meta es lograr crear un 2FA como lo tiene google,facebook,twitter, etc usando algún tipo de envió y verificación de código.
 Estaba pensando en usar Auhty pero creo que es necesario Arabel..
 También pensé en un método de envió de key al correo, pero seria muy inseguro por si le roban el correo al usuario; por lo que me gustaría crear un 2FA un poco mas robusto. 
 Alguien tiene idea de como crear un sistema como este usando PDO y php?.

y esta es mi tabla de usuarios en la base de datos

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pasword` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(2500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `bio` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `bloqueado` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `verify` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://github.com/RobThree/TwoFactorAuth

Comment: se puede implementar en mi código sin tener que modificarlo @DiegoAvila